# Get an array of user photos using FQL

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-fql

I'm to get a list of the users photos (one's they've been tagged in) using FQL. 
Basically I've go an array object like so: _imageAddressArray.

I can retrieve the users' photos using graphApi so I know it works, problem with graphAPi is that it's too slow (+15 seconds min for 100 photos).

So far I've got:

```
    //New Stuff
    FQL fql = new FQL(facebook);
    String FQLResult = null;

    try 
    {
        _userGallery = graphApi.getPhotosMy(_noOfPhotos);
        FQLResult = fql.fqlQuery("SELECT object_id, src_small FROM photo");
    } 
    catch (EasyFacebookError e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("FQL Result" + FQLResult);
```

This returns the error: 601, any ideas anyone?

Of course ideally FQLResult will be a string[] (string array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting an error because you don't have a `WHERE` clause in your FQL statement that references one of the indexed columns -- shown with a "*" [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/photo/)

To get the photos using FQL that your user has been tagged in, try this:

```
SELECT object_id, src_small FROM photo WHERE object_id IN 
  (SELECT object_id FROM photo_tag WHERE subject = me())
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this tonight and get back. One question, what will this return? What kind of array?